# convert an "Image" to an "XFile"

Tags: flutter

I want to convert the `Image` that my `CropController` returns, and feed it to my page and takes an `XFile` and posts it to firebase whilst also displaying it.

How do I do that? I don't want to use the `package:image/image.dart` version of Image, I want to use the default version.

To give a basic idea of my project: On flutter android, I take an image from camera/gallery, send it as XFile to image_cropper , and send the resultant XFile to firebase
However, this cannot be implemented for flutter web, so I made separate of code using `kIsWeb` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter by default gives you the image picker library and it returns the image in XFile Formate